# Button in widget not updating textview

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create an a button in an android widget that increments a value and sets it on the text view. But the value is not updating the counter-num.

Here is my DemoUI.java class

```
    package com.example.widget2;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DemoUI extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String MY_WIDGET_UPDATE="ACTION_BUTTON1"; 
    RemoteViews remoteViews;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        final String action=intent.getAction();
        if(intent.getAction().equals(MY_WIDGET_UPDATE)){

            int num;
            num=intent.getIntExtra("num",1);
            Toast.makeText(context, num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int []appWidgetIds){

        int num=1;
        ComponentName comp=new ComponentName(context,DemoUI.class);
        int []allWidgetIds=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(comp);

        for(int widgetIds:allWidgetIds){

            remoteViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
            Log.w("WidgetExample2",String.valueOf(num));

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text1, String.valueOf(++num));

            //register listener
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,DemoUI.class);
            intent.setAction(MY_WIDGET_UPDATE);
            //intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            intent.putExtra("num", num++);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

            //committing changes to the widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetIds, remoteViews);

        }
    }

}
```

// The text view displays only the num static value and not update it on clicking the button.

Comment: code for updating please share?

Comment: @TerrilThomas I am incrementing the value in onUpdate method using Remote Views.

Comment: Log ur remoteViews Value i guess its not incrementing

Comment: @TerrilThomas: I am getting the values now in the text view but only when I paste the widget onto the home screen and not by clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question: If the button on click does not respond, it means something wrong with the onReceive. Better to create a custom intent when using onReceive(). If any doubt or suggestions, do write and I 'll be happy to reply and improve..